# How to program to generate robot URDF(Serial manipulator) when having stl file of each link with Python

Tags: simulation, python, simulator

I've tried :

- to use [obj2udf library(PyPI)](https://pypi.org/project/object2urdf/)  then It can generate 1 URDF per 1 STL(it doesn't work because I can't find how to program to change link name or add link and can't combine STL)
  so now I have URDF of each link instead of a robot URDF.
- to combine each urdf in pybullet and think it won't work when use as simulation.
  additional :
- after I have URDF I will try to work with pybullet.
- I am working on window 10 with Visual studio code.
- use miniconda.

so is there a way or some function of python that can generate robot URDF

reference code:

```
import os
import sys
from object2urdf import ObjectUrdfBuilder

# Build single URDFs
object_folder = "Base"

builder = ObjectUrdfBuilder(object_folder, urdf_prototype='_prototype_Base.urdf')
builder.build_urdf(filename="Base\Base.stl", force_overwrite=True, decompose_concave=True, force_decompose=False, center = 'mass')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you,Now I have found [odio_urdf](https://github.com/hauptmech/odio_urdf) library that can generate urdf by programming in python like you code in  urdf file.

Comment: If you have found a solution, and your question has been answered, don't forget to mark the answer (in this case, your answer) as the accepted answer by clicking the tick icon next to the answer. That way, the question gets removed from the unanswered question list. Thanks.